# Create new property into an object depending to the value of another one

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

For an array of objects like this:

```
myArray = [
            {id: "1", type: "xxx"},
            {id: "2", type: "abc"},
            {id: "3", type: "xxx"},
            {id: "4", type: "yyy"}
];
```

if it's needed to create another property for each object which is influenced by the `type`'s value, for example:

if `type === xxx` then `newProp = prop1`

if `type === abc` then `newProp = prop2`

if `type === yyy` then `newProp = prop3`

the resulted array should look like:

```
myArray = [
            {id: "1", type: "xxx", newProp: "prop1"},
            {id: "2", type: "abc", newProp: "prop2"},
            {id: "3", type: "xxx", newProp: "prop1"},
            {id: "4", type: "yyy", newProp: "prop3"}
];
```

I did it with a for loop and lots of if statements but probably there is a more efficient solution that I don't know.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should show the code you've already attempted.

Comment: Why did you accept an answer that will create a new array instead to add a new property over the same array?  There are two answers (Nina's and Jonas') which solve your problem in a better way.

Comment: @Ele you're right. didn't notice that it cretes a new array because I defined the newProp as `myArray.newProp = [];` before performing the map. In this case is no need to declare it before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take an object with the wanted values of the types.

```js
var myArray = [{ id: "1", type: "xxx" }, { id: "2", type: "abc" }, { id: "3", type: "xxx" }, { id: "4", type: "yyy" }];

myArray.forEach(o => o.newProp = { xxx: 'prop1', abc: 'prop2', yyy: 'prop3' }[o.type]);

console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a map that holds the value to be added when one of the types is found. Then you can `map` over the array and return a new object with the appropriate value added as `newProp`:

```js
const map = { xxx: 'prop1', abc: 'prop2', yyy: 'prop3' };
const myArray = [{id: "1", type: "xxx"}, {id: "2", type: "abc"}, {id: "3", type: "xxx"}, {id: "4", type: "yyy"}];

const out = myArray.map(obj => {
  return { ...obj, newProp: map[obj.type] };
});

console.log(out)
```

Comment: Creating a new array to accomplish that scenario? Ummm wrong! Further, you don't need that return.

Comment: It's not _wrong_ - it's just a different way of reaching the same conclusion.

Comment: It's wrong for sure: *it's needed to create another property for each object which is influenced by the type's value* - that on the same array.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a functional js-one-liner, here goes:

```
// type2Prop is a object lookup table for type to newProp values
myArray.map(e => (v => v && (e.newProp = v))(type2Prop[e.type]))
```

**Note:** It also deals with the case, where if the `type` doesn't match anything in known types, it won't add a property.

Comment: Creating a new array to accomplish that scenario? Ummm wrong!

Comment: In fact, the same array also has the same objects, since the object reference doesn't change. So both original and new contain the update value. Change to `forEach` for just modifications on the source array

Answer (score 1):

Use `map`:

```js
let myArray = [{id: "1", type: "xxx"},{id: "2", type: "abc"},{id: "3", type: "xxx"},{id: "4", type: "yyy"}];
        
let resp = myArray.map(x => {
  if(x.type === 'xxx') x.newProp = 'prop1';
  if(x.type === 'abc') x.newProp = 'prop2';
  if(x.type === 'yyy') x.newProp = 'prop3';
  return x;
 })
    
console.log(resp);
```

Comment: why map instead of just forEach? you're not even using the return of the map.

Comment: Creating a new array to accomplish that scenario? Ummm wrong!

Comment: @Ele could you elaborate why using pure concepts are considered wrong in so affirmative way?

Comment: Because you're creating a new array and the OP wants to work on the same array.

Comment: @Ele It doesn't explicit OP wants resulted array to be same one. Only requirement here is to add a property to same object, and that's what my response do. *I'm not creating a new object*. console `resp` and `myArray` and you will see.

Comment: Look carefully the question's body.  My goodness, it's worst, you're looping using the function `map`, creating a new array and modifying the original array, I didn't realize that.

Comment: @Ele In fact, `myArray` just hold references and after `map` it still points to same things which, by definition, implies being same arr even when objects which its points to has been changed. *I'm not modifying original array*, if array had values instead of references then it would be clearer. Moreover, naming input and response by same doesn't implies being same arrays. If instead of creating `resp` I had reassigned `myArray`, I would have same variable but it **will be** a different array. Be careful with these few concepts.

Comment: @Ele  But yeah, I confess I'm not comfortable with my approach neither because doing this it's not pure at all and I don't agree doing any side effects when using functions like `map`, `filter`, etc. though I'm not confortable, it'd not wrong. cheers

Comment: @guijob fix that with a forEach to avoid any confusion in the community nor future OPs.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way, and add other types if needed:

```js
const myArray = [
  {id: "1", type: "xxx"},
  {id: "2", type: "abc"},
  {id: "3", type: "xxx"},
  {id: "4", type: "yyy"}
];
const types = {
  "xxx": "prop1",
  "abc": "prop2",
  "yyy": "prop3",
};
const newArray = myArray.map(e=>{
  return {...e, newProp: types[e.type]};
});
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  for(const el of myArray)
   el.newProp = {"xxx" : "prop1", "abc": "prop2" /*...*/ }[el.type];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following with Array's `map()`:

```js
var myArray = [
            {id: "1", type: "xxx"},
            {id: "2", type: "abc"},
            {id: "3", type: "xxx"},
            {id: "4", type: "yyy"}
];

myArray = myArray.map(function(i){
  if(i.type==='xxx') i.newProp='prop1'
  else if(i.type==='abc') i.newProp='prop2'
  else if(i.type==='yyy') i.newProp='prop3'
  return i;
});
console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: Creating a new array to accomplish that scenario? Ummm wrong!